# multiple array in function not show in result using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to print/show list of comments for articles using this PHP function:

```
function _is_comments_($id,$type){

    $db = mysqli_access::F("SELECT message FROM " . COMMENTS . " WHERE pid = ? AND type = ? AND approved = 1 ", $id, $type);

    foreach($db as $row){
      $commentdata['message'] = $row['message'];
    }
    return $commentdata;
}
```

In action :

```
$comments_list = _is_comments_('125','article');
print_r($comments_list);
```

In result :
 `Array ( [message] => this is a One comment )`

But in MySQL database I have `18` comments for article id `125` and my result is false and show only One result!

how do fix This ?!

Comment: You're overwriting the result entry in your loop.

Comment: @Mario: your mean is I remove `foreach` from function?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the assignment in the loop here:

```
foreach($db as $row){
  $commentdata['message'] = $row['message'];
}
```

Even if you got multiple result `$row`s, each iteration would overwrite the same `$commentdata['message']` key. Which is why you only get to see one entry when returned from the function.

Instead you want to *collect* multiple entries. I would just drop the `['message']` key, and use an additive indexed array:

```
foreach($db as $row){
  $commentdata[] = $row['message'];
}
```

This way your result array might contain:

```
 Array (
    [0] => this is a One comment
    [1] => this is a second comment
    [2] => third one
)
```

Comment: my result is :`Array(
 [0] => [1] => comments 1 [2] => sss[3] => sssss[4] => dsfgsdfgds[5] => dsddd[6] => rtrt[7] => ertertertertert[8] => dd[9] => xxxx[10] => rrrrrrrrr[11] => sdfgsdfg
)` how do can I print result in html code ?! sorry im new coder

Comment: With another loop for printing the HTML. (Please don't introduce new questions in comments. But also don't post new questions if it's overly trivial, and/or before you attempted something concrete.)

Comment: Ok,you right. I have Problem: I need to select other field ie: `usename` or `date` from database and show in my page how do add another field with your method?

Comment: If you're querying multiple fields, then just append the full `$row` itself to the result array. Such as `$commentdata[] = $row;`. That'll give you an indexed list of associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the message index an array.

```
$commentdata['message'][] = $row['message'];
```